# flyway upgrade from 6.5.3 to 9.17 breaks and gives setFlywayLocations,Java migrations classpath is null

Tags: flyway

when i upgrade flyway from 6.5.3 to 9.17 i found that i have to include flyway-mysql and gson as dependency post that when i run migrations only .class files are recognised and .sql files are not getting migrated so i am getting 2 errors in total

1. missing version because .sql are not migrated eg: v9 or v10 executing(.class) and getting some table not found as previoud files(.sql) are not migrated.
2. where there are no .class files i just get setFlywayLocations,Java migrations classpath is null

Note: i am using flyway-core in my java, DB: mysql,  flyway 6 works fine no prob

Thanks in advance and i can really use some help from this community.

i am expecting the migrations to work seemlessly after providing the dependencies.